# wxPython Rendering issues, very slow and crashes, not sure why

Tags: python, performance, crash, wxpython, render

I have been creating a simple tile based game to help me learn python and wx python. For starters I wanted to create my own 'world' and to test the simple map generator I made, I bound the return key to generate a new map and display it.
That is when I ran into this problem. It slows down a lot every time you click return, renders each tile line by line (which is obviously slow and inefficient) and eventually just freezes.

I am quite a novice programmer and have never dealt with any form of GUI so this is all very new to me, please bear with me! I can guess that the way I have things set up is very taxing for the machine, and that perhaps I'm causing a lot of recursion. I'm simply unaware. Also I'm not too familiar with OOP so I just follow examples to create my classes (hence why I only have 1 massive class that handles everything, Im not too sure on all the '__ something__' functions.)

Here is all the code I have written so far, please ignore commented-out sections, they are for future functions etc:

```
import wx
import random


#main screen class, handles all events within the main screen
class MainScreen(wx.Frame):

    hMap = []
    tTotalX = 50
    tTotalY = 50

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #This line is equivilant to wx.Frame.__init__('stuff')
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(None, -1, 'You shouldnt see this', style = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)

        self.renderScreen()

    def genMap(self,tTotalX,tTotalY):
        count1 = 0
        count2 = 0
        self.hMap = []
        while count1 < tTotalY:
            count2 = 0
            newrow = []
            while count2 < tTotalX: 
                newrow.append(random.randint(1,120))
                count2 += 1
            self.hMap.append(newrow)
            count1 += 1
        self.smooth(tTotalX, tTotalY)
        self.smooth(tTotalX, tTotalY)


    def smooth(self, tTotalX, tTotalY):
        countx = 0
        county = 0
        while county < tTotalY:
            countx = 0

            while countx < tTotalX: 
                above = county - 1
                below = int(county + 1)
                east = int(countx + 1)
                west = int(countx - 1)
                if east >= tTotalX:
                    east = 0
                if west < 0:
                    west = tTotalX -1

                teast = self.hMap[county][east]
                twest = self.hMap[county][west]

                if above < 0 or below >= tTotalY: 
                    smooth = (self.hMap[county][countx] + teast + twest)/3
                else:
                    tabove = self.hMap[above][countx]
                    tbelow = self.hMap[below][countx]
                    smooth = (self.hMap[county][countx] + tabove + tbelow + teast + twest)/5

                self.hMap[countx][county] = int(smooth)               
                countx += 1

            county += 1        

    def getTileType(self, coordX, coordY, totalX, totalY):
        #this is the part of map creation, getting tile type based on tile attributes
        tType = ''
        height = self.hMap[coordX][coordY]
        #the below values are all up to tweaking in order to produce the best maps
        if height <= 55:
            tType = 'ocean.png'

        if height > 55:
            tType = 'coast.png'

        if height > 60:
            tType = 'grassland.png'

        if height > 75:
            tType = 'hills.png'

        if height > 80:
            tType = 'mountain.png'

        if tType == '':
            tType = 'grassland.png'

        return tType

    #render the main screen so that it dislays all data
    def renderScreen(self):
        frameSize = 810 #Size of the game window
        tTotalX = self.tTotalX #the dimensions of the tile display, setting for in-game coordinates
        tTotalY = self.tTotalY
        #tsTiny = 1 #ts = Tile Size
        #tsSmall = 4
        tsMed = 16
        #tsLrg = 32
        #tsXlrg = 64
        tsCurrent = tsMed #the currently selected zoom level, for now fixed at tsMed
        pposX = 0 #ppos = Pixel Position
        pposY = 0
        tposX = 0 #tpos = tile position, essentially the tile co-ordinates independent of pixel position
        tposY = 0
    #The below is just an example of how to map out the grid, it should be in its own function in due time

        self.genMap(tTotalX, tTotalY)

        while tposY < tTotalY: #loops through all y coordinates
            tposX = 0   
            while tposX < tTotalX: #loops through all x coordinates
                pposX = tposX*tsCurrent
                pposY = tposY*tsCurrent
                tiletype = self.getTileType(tposX,tposY,tTotalX,tTotalY)

                img = wx.Image(('F:\First Pass\\' + str(tiletype)), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
                wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, img, (pposX, pposY))#paints the image object (i think)

                tposX += 1
            tposY += 1

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onclick)
        self.SetSize((frameSize-4, frameSize+16))
        self.SetBackgroundColour('CYAN')
        self.Centre()
        self.SetTitle('Nations First Pass')
        #string = wx.StaticText(self, label = 'Welcome to Nations, First Pass', pos = (tTotalX*tsCurrent/2,tsCurrent*tTotalY/2))
        #string.SetFont(wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT))

        self.Show()

    def onclick(self, e):
        key = e.GetKeyCode()

        if key == wx.WXK_RETURN:

            self.renderScreen()


 #game loop
     def main():
         app = wx.App()
         MainScreen(None)
         app.MainLoop()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

You will need to fabricate your own 'ocean.png' 'coast.png' 'grassland.png' 'hills.png' and 'mountain.png' (they need to be 16x16 pixels) or you can use mine from the Imgur link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rNnT.jpg

Also please change the file path in the img code as appropriate. I need to figure out how to set that to do it itself as well but thats another challenge for another day.

If you have any insight into this I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new set of wx.StaticBitmaps each time renderScreen is called, and you are not deleting them before creating a new set. After a while you'll have gobs of widgets stacked up with the old ones no longer visible, but still there consuming resources.  At a minimum you should change things so your program makes only one set of wx.StaticBitmaps, keeps track of them, and then call their SetBitmap method when you want to change them.

For even better performance you should forget about the StaticBitmaps and draw the images yourself in an EVT_PAINT handler.  StaticBitmaps are intended to be "static", IOW not changing very much.  Instead you can implement an EVT_PAINT handler for the window and it will be called whenever the window needs to be redrawn, and you can trigger new redraws simply by calling the window's Refresh method.